# 'like anything' as an intensifier

Tags: adverbs

I have seen a person using 'like anything' as intensifier.
Freedictionary website gave these example of 'like anything':-

1. **He ran like anything.**
   (intensifier; usually euphemistic)
2. **We worked like anything to meet the deadline.**
   (To an exceeding degree)

Please tell me is this usage common? 
Also tell me if there are some alternative phrases which I can use in most of the sentences.

Comment: It's a bit "dated/childish". You're more likely to hear *like crazy* or *like mad* today (or perhaps *like hell, like the devil* from older speakers).

Comment: 'like crazy' is good especially in informal situation ,thanks.

Comment: I think we dont use intensifiers in formal situation, right?

Answer (score 3):

As a native English speaker, I find "like anything" as an intensifier to be easily understood. It strikes me as a euphemism for "like hell." It probably came from "like hell was after him," meaning that the worst possible consequence would befall him if he failed to complete the task in time.

Comment: Easily understood? Yes. Particularly common? I would say no. A little awkward? Again, I think yes.

Comment: Agreed, @Daniel.

Comment: I think it's a bit simplistic (narrow-minded, even) to suppose *anything* is specifically a euphemism for *hell*. OP's  examples could just as easily be expressed *"He ran like **the wind**"*, *"We worked like **Trojans**"*. Or indeed, they could both be replaced by **like fuck** if you wanted to be profane. I certainly don't accept that "anything* "came from" euphemistic substitution of *hell* - some if not most people would always have just used the general-purpose word because off-hand they can't think of the "archetypal example" for whatever comparison they're trying to make.

Answer (score 1):

You asked for alternative phrases; there are quite a few, depending both on the context and the degree of formality you want, and on whether you want to use a metaphor at all.

E.g.

He ran like a bat out of hell - very casual; only used for speed.

He worked like a dog - casual; used for effort.

She worked like the dickens - quite old fashioned.

and many others

of course you could use
She ran very fast or
She worked very hard.

Comment: You caught the second part of the question that I missed. Feel free to incorporate my answer's information into yours for a complete answer.