# They worked as (if) crazy

Tags: as, as-like

> **Like** "as if '' is standard in informal speech and writing with some
> adjectives: *They worked like crazy/mad*.
>
> https://www.wordreference.com/definition/like

Is *They worked as if crazy* grammatically correct?

What about *They worked as crazy* ?

Comment: The utterance is already "reduced" from *They worked as if **they were** crazy*. Discarding even more words leaves you with syntactic nonsense, imho. The basic construction *can* occur - for example, ***We speak as one*** (we are united). But it's a "poetic / literary" form that usually *won't* be remotely idiomatic, so I suggest you simply forget about the possibility of using it yourself.

Comment: ...note that idiomatically it's fine to say *They worked **like** crazy* (or [***like mad***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/like-mad)).

Comment: Related: ['like anything' as an intensifier](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9478/like-anything-as-an-intensifier)

Comment: @FumbleFingers https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/as_one , https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/like_crazy

Comment: You could say 1) *they worked like crazy* or 2) *they worked as if they were crazy*

Answer (score 1):

> They worked **like** *crazy*.

Check out definition 13. It says *like* means *as if*.

> They worked **as if** *crazy*.

which, in turn, a shorten version of

> They worked **as if** *they were crazy*.

*They worked as crazy* isn't semantically right. They are not mad, they just appeared to be crazy by the way they worked. Perhaps, they worked too energetically, too frantically, too enthusiastically.

It isn't correct grammatically either. We prefer *like* for comparison. You compare *them* with *crazy-looking people*.